# Set fixed size and disable resizing, tkinter maximize window and restore window

Tags: python, tkinter, fullscreen, tk-toolkit, ttk

i'm having an issue with this code i want to set a fixed window size and disable resizing, once it restored from ***zoomed***

My code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
w = w - 200

h = root.winfo_screenheight()
h = h - 500

root.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+0+0')

root.state("zoomed")


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable resizing, you use this function

```
root.resizable(False, False)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: i've already tried this method, unfortunately it didn't work for me, once i added this function it disable the maximize/ restore button, i cannot shrink the window to a fixed window size.

Comment: So if you still want it to be resizable, then how about setting a max size for the window by calling
root.maxsize(height, width)

Comment: Thanks :) . For me root.minsize( height, width ) works for me, its not what I was looking for but it's ok for now. It'll do the job. ;)